# 'Asked by' different on mobile site and desktop site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[image: Desktop wobsite]

[image: Mobile wesbite]

On the mobile view, it display the last user who answered the question, but on the desktop view it display the user who asked the question.

Is it the expected behaviour?

Comment: To be fair, there is no `asked by` line in the mobile interface.

Answer (score 1):

The mobile view is showing the details of the latest answer.

That particular question was most recently answered by `Angrybird` on Feb 19th.

Comment: Yeah, but...why? It doesn't make much sense to be inconsistent between mobile/full on the same view.